# SQL QUERY FOR PAIRS

Tags: sql

I have the following values in my table

```
A B
1 2
2 3 
4 5 
2 1 
5 6
7 6
6 5
```

what a sql query in order to find the results which have a pair so this is the output is

```
1 2 
2 1 
5 6 
6 5
```

Comment: Do a self join.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like there're already great solutions:

```
SELECT t.A, t.B FROM table AS t1 INNER JOIN table AS t2 ON t1.A = t2.B AND t1.B = t2.A
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 WITH CTE(A,B) AS
 (

  SELECT 1, 2 UNION ALL 
  SELECT 2, 3 UNION ALL 
  SELECT 4, 5 UNION ALL 
  SELECT 2 ,1 UNION ALL 
  SELECT 5, 6 UNION ALL 
  SELECT 7, 6 UNION ALL 
  SELECT 6 ,5 
 )
 SELECT C.A,C.B
    FROM CTE AS C
     JOIN CTE AS C2 ON C.A=C2.B AND C.B=C2.A
```

Answer (score 0):

This is another way to do it. With Self join

```
SELECT t1.* 
FROM table1 t1
table1 t2 ON t1.a = t2.b AND t2.a = t1.b
```

Answer (score 0):

Doing an Inner join will help you in this case:

```
SELECT t.col1, t.col2 
FROM Tablename t
INNER JOIN Tablename t2
ON t.col1 = t2.col2 AND t.col2 = t2.col1
```

This will give you the required result:
**Sample Output :**

| Innings | Totalplayer |
| --- | --- |
| 2 | 1 |
| 1 | 2 |
| 6 | 5 |
| 5 | 6 |

[View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/6A7ASiCHrJMU1wCoMDL5L2/3)